# I can't get ios data saved on its memory (xamarin.forms - interface)

Tags: ios, interface, xamarin.forms, nsuserdefaults, user-preferences

app delegate:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // Get current device token
        var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
        {
            DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
        }

        // Get previous device token
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("token");

        // Has the token changed?
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
        {
            //TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that the device token has changed/been created!
        }

        // Save new device token
        //NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "token");
        IOSUserPreferences userPreference = new IOSUserPreferences();
        userPreference.SetString("token", DeviceToken);
    }
```

my PCL interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace neoFly_Montana
{
public interface IUserPreferences
{
    void SetString(string key, string value);
    string GetString(string key);
}
}
```

when I call the interface in pcl:

```
string token = App.UserPreferences.GetString("token");
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace neoFly_Montana
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2()) { BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#f98e1e") };
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }

    public static IUserPreferences UserPreferences { get; private set; }

    public static void Init(IUserPreferences userPreferencesImpl)
    {
        App.UserPreferences = userPreferencesImpl;
    }
}
}
```

on iphone project:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace neoFly_Montana.iOS
{
class IOSUserPreferences : IUserPreferences
{
    public void SetString(string key, string value)
    {
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, key);
    }

    public string GetString(string key)
    {
        return NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(key);
    }
}
}
```

on Android it works fine, saves and gets the data...

as a test, I tried to save a data and get it on app delegate and it worked fine, I could see it accesing the IOSUserPreferences script, the problens occurs when I try to get it on pcl

when I try to get the data that is saved, only in ios, it's null and app crashes...I noticed that it doesn't access the **get string** method on iphone project...
Does someone know what is happening ?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you call the Init() method

Comment: In the iOS project where are you calling the `App.Init()` method injecting your `IUserPreferences`  implementation?

Comment: That is it!!!!! Thank you very much!! I was crazy for sure..